# Effect on data on Changing mysql database from 'utf8' to 'utf8mb4' in django live application

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, encoding

I am serving Django application with MySQL back-end with Apache 2. I have configured the database with character-set set to 'utf8'
I want to store emojis as well so I need to change the encoding to 'utf8mb4'
I just want to know if i change my configuration will will it affect my data?
this is my mysql.cnf file

```
[client]
database = 'databasename'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
default-character-set = utf8
```

This is my django settings for mysql database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/mysql.cnf'
        }
    }
}
```

What effect will it have on my previously saved data?
Also, How shall I do it
Should I straight forwardly add the `default-character-set = utf8mb4` to my default configuration file.

Comment: Hi @saksham, were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: @YoYo Yup! Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DJango:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
```

**my.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-collation=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

But, you also need to **change the table definitions**:

Assuming the table is `CHARACTER SET utf8` and correctly encoded in utf8; want utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

To change one column is `CHARACTER SET utf8` that is correctly encoded in utf8; and you want utf8mb4 without touching other columns:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

(Be sure to keep the other specifications the same - VARCHAR, NOT NULL, etc.)

**more**

Any correctly encoded data in the tables will be converted to utf8mb4 (virtually a no-op).

To experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE test LIKE existing_table;
SHOW CREATE TABLE;  -- to see the old schema
INSERT INTO test SELECT * FROM existing_table;
ALTER TABLE test CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
SHOW CREATE TABLE;  -- to see the new schema
SELECT * FROM test;  -- to see the data
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM test WHERE ...;  -- to check encoding
```

Where

```
`existing_table` is some table with utf8 characters in it.
`col` and `...` limit the SELECT to one row with accented letters.
```

Comment: Okay so my old data won't be affected?

Comment: Thank you for specifications but i have many tables so is there a way i can change the whole database to utfmb4?

Comment: @Saksham - Sorry.  The best you can get is `SELECT CONCAT(...) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql', ...)` to build the `ALTERs` needed.

Comment: A very important question, Will my old data be affected?The data is encoded in utf8.

Comment: @Saksham - I added to my Answer.